# I have a warning error when plotting with plotly

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook, plotly, ipython

I am plotting one of the first examples in Plotly:

```py
import plotly.graph_objects as go
fig = go.Figure(data=go.Bar(y=[2, 3, 1]))
fig.show()
```

but I have the following warning:

```py
**/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.8/site-packages/google/colab/data_table.py:30: UserWarning:
IPython.utils.traitlets has moved to a top-level traitlets package.**
```

I think it is probably some installation issue. Here are some the versions of Jupyter

- jupyter core     : 4.6.3
- jupyter-notebook : 6.1.5
- qtconsole        : 4.7.5
- ipython          : 7.19.0
- ipykernel        : 5.3.4
- jupyter client   : 6.1.6
- jupyter lab      : 2.1.5
- nbconvert        : 5.6.1
- ipywidgets       : 7.5.1
- nbformat         : 5.0.7
- traitlets        : 4.3.3

Please let me know if you have any clue on this!!!!!
Thanks!

Comment: Tried it on my anaconda 3.7 inside jupyter.   
Did "!pip install plotly" from jupyter
Then ran code.... showed plot ok,

Comment: I just did that and I still have the same problem

Comment: One diff is I'm using py3.7... and seems you are using py3.8.... 
Try installing py3.7 and see if that changes things.

Comment: I check diff of my install vs yours:

package                           OK.                ISSUE
ipykernel                          5.1.4 : 5.3.4
ipython                            7.12.0 : 7.19.0
ipywidgets                         7.5.1 : 7.5.1
nbconvert                          5.6.1 : 5.6.1
nbformat                           5.0.4 : 5.0.7
qtconsole                          4.6.0 : 4.7.5
traitlets                          4.3.3 : 4.3.3

Answer (score 0):

All this message is telling you that on *line 30* in the file `**/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.8/site-packages/google/colab/data_table.py` the import call for `traitlets` is now a top-level package instead of a module within `IPython.utils`. So you can just call `traitlets` directly instead of from IPython.

To solve it, you can open the file `**/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.8/site-packages/google/colab/data_table.py`, make the change below on line 30. Then the message will go away.

```
from IPython.utils import traitlets as _traitlets
```

Should be changed to

```
import traitlets as _traitlets
```

If you have problems with your plot showing, you may need to change the inline magic for `matplotlib` to

```
%matplotlib auto
```